# How to fix Rails 6 and React.js webpacker manifest issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index

Webpacker can't find hello_react in /Users/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-12a806211a6b97e3fbdb.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-12a806211a6b97e3fbdb.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-12a806211a6b97e3fbdb.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-12a806211a6b97e3fbdb.js.map"
      ]
    }
```

Following along to an article to add realtime search to an existing Rails 6 app with React.js in development environment. Added the javascript_pack_tag to the application.html.erb file and the file to execute realtime search.

I've updated homebrew, npm, yarn and reinstalled webpacker numerous times and am still receiving the error message above. Would there be a workaround to manipulate the webpacker.yml file or would there be a better approach?

Comment: try install webpacker **rails webpacker:install**

Comment: @monim tried installing webpack. I'm receiving a build failed with error code: 1

Comment: follow theese steps   : **To include Webpacker in a new project, add --webpack to the rails new command. To add Webpacker to an existing project, add the webpacker gem to the project's Gemfile, run bundle install, and then run bin/rails webpacker:install**